# UITextView Draw Invisible/Whitespace Characters

Tags: swift, uitextview, whitespace

How would I make a `UITextView` draw invisible characters for tabs, spaces, and newline endings?

I figure it would have to be handled either in the `drawRect(CGRect)`  method or by the layout manager in Text Kit. Any simple and/or intuitive solutions?

I just need to know how to get the `CGRect` of each whitespace character and which method of override to seamlessly draw a graphic for each whitespace character?

Thanks in advance for any advice/help.
Also, I don't mind if your answer in objective-c although both languages would be preferred.

Comment: Read the apple documentation on the text layout system. Text editing is not an easy topic and there are many classes involved like NSLayoutManager, NSTextView, NSTextContainer, NSTypeSetter. It's been a while, but you will probably need a custom NSLayoutManager (on iOS) or a custom NSTypeSetter (on OS X).

It's certainly doable to replace invisible characters by a custom (visible) character, but it's not going to be as easy as overriding drawRect in NSTextView.

Comment: @user965972 I already have a custom NSLayoutManager and custom NSTextStorage that enables line numbering and indentation of wrapped lines for its text views. I am very familiar with Text Kit, but I was hoping someone could give me a hint as to a most acceptable practice used in production to custom draw in whitespace characters graphics

Comment: In that case: layout manager has functions to generate NSGlyphs from the characters (it's not a one-to-one relation, though). Override one of these functions to inject your custom NSGlyph for a white space character.

You don't have to do any drawing yourself. You just have to specify which glyph should be drawn by the text system.

Comment: Oh, and the glyph depends on the font. The glyph is just the numerical representation of the on-screen image of a (set of) character(s) and so depends on the font.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a better solution than setting the `showsInvisibleCharacters` property of `NSLayoutManager` to `true`, by subclassing  `NSLayoutManager` and overriding the method `drawBackgroundForGlyphRange(NSRange, CGPoint)`, which allows for custom drawings for each whitespace character, for example:

```
class LayoutManager : NSLayoutManager {

    var text: String? { return textStorage?.string }

    var font: UIFont = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(UIFont.systemFontSize()) { 
        didSet { 
            guard let text = self.text else { return }
            let textRange = NSMakeRange(0, (text as NSString).length)                
            invalidateGlyphsForCharactersInRange(textRange, actualCharacterRange: nil)
            invalidateCharacterAttributesForCharactersInRange(textRange, actualCharacterRange: nil)
        }
    }

    override func drawBackgroundForGlyphRange(glyphsToShow: NSRange, atPoint origin: CGPoint) {

        super.drawBackgroundForGlyphRange(glyphsToShow, atPoint:origin)

        guard let text = self.text else { return }

        enumerateLineFragmentsForGlyphRange(glyphsToShow)
        { (rect: CGRect, usedRect: CGRect, textContainer: NSTextContainer, glyphRange: NSRange, stop: UnsafeMutablePointer<ObjCBool>) -> Void in

            let characterRange = self.characterRangeForGlyphRange(glyphRange, actualGlyphRange: nil)

            // Draw invisible tab space characters

            let line = (self.text as NSString).substringWithRange(characterRange)

            do {

                let expr = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: "\t", options: [])

                expr.enumerateMatchesInString(line, options: [.ReportProgress], range: line.range) 
                { (result: NSTextCheckingResult?, flags: NSMatchingFlags, stop: UnsafeMutablePointer<ObjCBool>) in

                    if let result = result {

                        let range = NSMakeRange(result.range.location + characterRange.location, result.range.length)
                        let characterRect = self.boundingRectForGlyphRange(range, inTextContainer: textContainer)

                        let symbol = "\u{21E5}"
                        let attrs = [NSFontAttributeName : Font]
                        let height = (symbol as NSString).sizeWithAttributes(attrs).height
                        symbol.drawInRect(CGRectOffset(characterRect, 1.0, height * 0.5, withAttributes: attrs)

                    }

                }

            } catch let error as NSError {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }

        }

    }

}
```